# How to register Automapper 5.0 with Microsoft Dependency Injection?

Tags: dependency-injection, automapper

I am trying to register the new Automapper 5.0 with Microsoft's built in dependency injection:

```
public static class ServicesContainerConfigure
{
    public static void Configure(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //This line fails because Mapper has no default constructor
        services.TryAddScoped<IMapper, Mapper>();

        var profileType = typeof(Profile);
        // Get an instance of each Profile in the executing assembly.
        var profiles = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
            .Where(t => profileType.IsAssignableFrom(t)
                        && t.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null)
            .Select(Activator.CreateInstance)
            .Cast<Profile>();

        // Initialize AutoMapper with each instance of the profiles found.
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            foreach (var profile in profiles)
            {
                cfg.AddProfile(profile);
            }
        });
        config.CreateMapper();
    }
}
```

There is no default constructor in the Mapper object. There must be a way to register this without registering all of the injected objects in the mapper dll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AddXXX` methods usually provide an overload where you can pass an "implementation factory".  It would seem `TryAddXXX` doesn't though.  If there's no compelling reason to use `TryAddXXX` then this should work for you:

```
services.AddScoped<IMapper>(_ =>
{
    var profileType = typeof(Profile);
    // Get an instance of each Profile in the executing assembly.
    var profiles = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                           .Where(t => profileType.IsAssignableFrom(t) && t.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null)
                           .Select(Activator.CreateInstance)
                           .Cast<Profile>();

    // Initialize AutoMapper with each instance of the profiles found.
    var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        foreach (var profile in profiles)
        {
            cfg.AddProfile(profile);
        }
    });

    return config.CreateMapper();
});
```